# How to change the direction of my text from right to left in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, right-to-left

I'm trying to store a text in oracle 11g (I'm using Arabic with English characters) and i want them to be formatted from right to left.

I tried to put RLM character in the beginning (formatting control character) but it appears as a question mark '?' and doesn't change anything.

```
NLS_Characterset: AR8MSWIN1256

NLS_NCHAR_Characterset: AL16UTF16
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest Solution is to use the REVERSE() Function on the specific Field. 
AFAIK there is no databas/Sessionwide Setting for that.

Try:

```
SELECT REVERSE('Stackoverflow') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I'm not trying to reverse the text. I need it to be stored from right to left coz it contains Arabic text.

Is there any function that determines wither the text is stored LTR or RTL ?